# fillRect not showing

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to code a game about snowboarding but so far, when I try to make trees (green rectangles), they aren't showing up.

Code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 800;

var x = canvas.width / 2,
  speed = 0.1,
  size = 5,
  alive = 1,
  keys = [];

function player() {
  if (alive === 1) {
    if (keys[37] || keys[65]) {
      x -= 3;
    }
    if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {
      x += 3;
    }

    if (x > canvas.width) {
      x = canvas.width;
    }
    if (x < 0) {
      x = 0;
    }


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"
    ctx.arc(x, 100, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

  }

}

function tree() {
  var treeX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width + 1)) + 25;
  var treeY;
  if (treeY < 1) {
    treeY = canvas.height;
  } else {
    treeY -= speed;
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(treeX, treeY, 5, 8);

}

function update() {
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  player();

  tree();

}

update();

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I tried switching the order of things and using console to see where the trees are but none worked.

Comment: `var treeY; if (treeY < 1) { treeY = canvas.height; } else { treeY -= speed; }` Here `treeY` will always be `NaN`, that is because the first line `var treeY` initializes it to `undefined`, so we end in the `else` block, and `undefined - 0.1` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

For `player`, you are tracking *state* outside of the function in some different variables.

For a tree to be able to update, you also have to track its state.

Here's a way you can do that:

- Instead of always initializing `treeX` and `treeY` fresh in the function, pass values as arguments
- After updating the tree state, return its `x` and `y` coordinates
- Outside of your `tree` function, keep track of a list of trees.
- In `update`, replace your list of trees with updated trees.

Here's a running example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 200;

var x = canvas.width / 2,
  speed = 1,
  size = 5,
  alive = 1,
  keys = [],
  trees = [ tree(), tree(), tree() ];

function player() {
  if (alive === 1) {
    if (keys[37] || keys[65]) {
      x -= 3;
    }
    if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {
      x += 3;
    }

    if (x > canvas.width) {
      x = canvas.width;
    }
    if (x < 0) {
      x = 0;
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"
    ctx.arc(x, 100, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
  }

}

function tree(
  treeX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width + 1)),
  treeY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.height + 1))
) {
  if (treeY < 1) {
    treeY = canvas.height;
  } else {
    treeY -= speed;
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(treeX, treeY, 5, 8);
  
  return [ treeX, treeY ];
}

function update() {
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  player();
  trees = trees.map(([x, y]) => tree(x, y));
}

update();

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; }
canvas { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```